# Can't get Win32::NetResource

Tags: perl, activestate

I have some code using an old perl version on a live server and I want to get it working on a new activestate installation on my laptop. I am getting an error message complaining about Win32::NetResource not being there. I have tried to locate it on activestate, but have failed. The current version is 5.34 but the working system that presumably has the module is on 5.26.

Another server with a recent starawberry perl doesn't have the module either - worried that it might not be supported any longer.

Comment: Should be able to install it with `cpanm` using Strawberry perl.

Comment: So I should uninstall activestate and go for strawberry instead?

Comment: That seems to be the usual recommendation these days for perl on Windows.